# Ghost .mdb File

Tags: database, vb.net, windows-8.1

So today I try, of all things, to create an mdb file with VB.NET (2012) and DAO. Please see following:

```
  Dim myEngine As New DAO.DBEngine


Sub CreateMDBFile()

    myEngine.CreateDatabase("C:\Windows\Test.mdb", ";LANGID=0x0409;CP=1252;COUNTRY=0", 64)

End Sub
```

It seems to work great. Code executes, and I have other subroutines that create and populate tables. I can retrieve data from recordsets, the whole 9 yards. There's just one weird issue:

When I open Explorer, I can't find the mdb file. It's not there. I mean, my program can find it, open it, populate it and query it -- But as far as Windows Explorer is concerned, there's nothing there.

Is this a Win 8 bug? Why won't my mdb file show up in Windows Explorer?

Thanks in Advance,

Jason

Comment: Are you sure your Explorer is set up to see hidden files?

Comment: That's a really poor directory to put your database in.  You should select `Environment.GetFolderPath(...)` instead.

Comment: And probably, being able to create a file in that directory, means that you have lowered every protection provided by the OS. Very bad for your security

Comment: Funny, as much as I agree with everyone else on this I'm stuck with my client's demands. And because of his demands, I get a -1 vote. Not fair :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an application not "Run As Administrator" (UAC) attempts to write to a system folder (including Program Files subdirectories), Windows no longer returns an error.  Instead, the file is saved in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\VirtualStore`.  This behavior started in Windows Vista.

http://blogs.windows.com/windows/archive/b/developers/archive/2009/08/04/user-account-control-data-redirection.aspx

**TIP:** Don't save user files to system folders.

Comment: Thanks for that. Now it appears I have to begin a new thread on how to run this little program as administrator every time, without a prompt. The specs for this project are a dire pain...